# how does this set delegate method work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

These are my delegate methods in Child view controller.

```
@protocol assignNames<NSObject>

-(void)setFirstName:(NSString*)firstName;
-(void)setLastName:(NSString*)lastName;

@end`
```

In my parent view controller, I receive the first name in a text field.
Here is a part of my code .

VIEWCONTROLLER.M

```
\\ FirstName is the name of my textField string


viewcontroller2 *viewc = [[viewcontroller2 alloc]init];
viewc2 = [segue destinationViewController];
viewc2.FNT = FirstName.text;   

[viewc2 setDelegate:self ]; \\ Here is my question
```

So, when I give this method, what it actually means?? as nothing seems to happen if i include it in my code .

Comment: `viewcontroller2 *viewc = [[viewcontroller2 alloc]init]; viewc2 = [segue destinationViewController];` should be changed to `viewcontroller2 *viewc = [segue destinationViewController];`

Comment: yup that first line is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@protocol` block in your `childviewController` is a list of methods that a delegate of the `childviewController` should implement. When you call `[viewc2 setDelegate:self ]` from `viewController.m`, your `viewController` becomes a delegate of your `childViewController`.

So what does all these steps do? Well, firstly, because the parent VC subscribes to the `assignNames` delegate, it will have those two methods implemented. Secondly, the Child VC can call the protocol's methods in the parent VC like so:

```
[self.delegate setFirstName:@"Derp"];
// we are in the child VC and the delegate would be parent VC
```

Anyways, there was a time when all this baffled me, so I know how it is. I suggest you go through some tutorials to get a hang of the stuff, like [this one here](http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002).

Comment: Thank You . Thats a useful link .